# Jersey number for Kobe Bryant

Tags: history, basketball, trivia, uniform

Kobe Bryant has played in NBA with only two jersey numbers - 8 and 24. Why these numbers? What is the history behind these numbers?

Comment: Related question: http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2131/jersey-number-for-lebron-james

Comment: Meta discussion: http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/315/questions-about-why-a-player-wears-a-certain-jersey-number

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An [article](http://sports.espn.go.com/nba/news/story?id=2421874) on ESPN.com from 2006 deals with this, although it doesn't site Kobe as a source and even says "Why's Kobe switching jersey numbers? Your guess is as good as ours" (more on this below).

In regard to the number 8 (and confirmed [here](http://www.nba.com/lakers/news/behind_the_numbers.html)):

> Bryant arrived at the No. 8 for two reasons. It was the number he wore when he was a kid playing in Italy. It also tied into the number he wore at Adidas' ABCD Camp, 143. The numbers add up to 8.

In why he took 24:

> Bryant began his career at Lower Merion High School in Ardmore, Pa., wearing No. 24. But by 1996 -- the year he led the school to the state championship -- he had switched to No. 33, the number his father Joe "Jelly Bean" Bryant wore in high school.

Information around the web seems to confirm these ideas, but first-hand accounts of the switch from 8 to 24 appear to be lacking.

There are some theories out there that Kobe wanted to "one up" Michael Jordan, who wore 23 for the Bulls, but the sources for this ([here](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Why_did_Kobe_Bryant_change_his_jersey_number_from_8_to_24)) are more sketchy than the stuff quoted above. Additional theories, including an increase in jersey sales, can be found in this [blog post](http://www.athleteslivehere.com/blog/2012/04/445/).

Answer (score 4):

Bryant wore #8 for the following reasons:

- He wore this number playing in Italy as a child.
- He wore #143 at the Adidas' ABCD Camp. Added together, this comes out
  to 8.
- #24 (or #33) was not available when he joined the team in 1996. #24 was worn by George McCloud. (#33 is retired in honor of Kareem Abdul-Jabbar.)

Bryant currently wears #24 for the following reason:

- He wore this number as he played high school basketball at Lower Merion High School (Bryant also wore #33 in honor of his father).

Sources: ([1](http://sports.espn.go.com/nba/news/story?id=2421874)), ([2](http://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/LAL/1997.html))

Comment: In addition, jersey sales is a speculatory theory why Bryant changed his number.

Comment: I think your comment is the real reason for changing the jersey number